# do the element ids of the documents in a frameset have to be unique

Tags: html

I know that in html my element id has to be unique (document wide).

But when it comes to frames:

I have to maintain an old web application, and I have to change some parts.

When I have frames, a frameset.

Can I have, for instance, the id "main" multiple times, once in a single frame document,
or means "document wide" all frames in a frameset.

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: this should be fine. no conflict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have the same `id` attribute value in different documents, and documents displayed in frames are treated as different.